# Implement DataTemplate DependencyProperty in UserControl

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, datatemplate, dependency-properties

I'm trying to make an intertia touch scrolling list in a UserControl in Silverlight 4 using Expression Blend 4. I've already made the dependency properties in my UserControl which i want to work like the ListBox does. ItemSource is the list of objects i want to show in my list and datatemplate is the way it should be shown.

How do i deal with these properties inside my UserControl? I have a StackPanel where all the datatemplates should be added showing the data ofc.

How do i apply the data in my IEnumerable to the DataTemplate when looping through the ItemSource to add them to the list (StackPanel).

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(InertiaScrollBox), null); 
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get{ return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(InertiaScrollBox), null);
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
```

This was kinda hard to explain but hope you understand otherwise please ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you might be better off either subclassing the ListBox or using a behavior. Usually dependency properties are used on a Control rather than a UserControl.

Comment: Using control templates or inheriting existing controls might be better, but we don't know all the details and the question is about data templates.

Comment: I'm creating a touch inertia scroll list. Subclassing ListBox made it hard for me to catch all the mouse events as per default left mouse down is catched by the ListBoxItem control inside the ListBox. Maybe it could be done but I think it would be more complicated than what i got now which works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency properties are rather useless if to not handle their changes.
At first you should add PropertyChanged callbacks. In my example I add them inline and call the `UpdateItems` private method.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(InertiaScrollBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata((s, e) => ((InertiaScrollBox)s).UpdateItems()));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(InertiaScrollBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata((s, e) => ((InertiaScrollBox)s).UpdateItems()));
```

Then you can call the `LoadContent` method of the `DataTemplate` class and set an item from the `ItemsSource` as the DataContext to the returned visual element:

```
private void UpdateItems()
{
    //Actually it is possible to use only the ItemsSource property,
    //but I would rather wait until both properties are set
    if(this.ItemsSource == null || this.ItemTemplate == null)
        return;

    foreach (var item in this.ItemsSource)
    {
        var visualItem = this.ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
        if(visualItem != null)
        {
            visualItem.DataContext = item;
            //Add the visualItem object to a list or StackPanel
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out yesterday but haven't had time to fill in the answer. This is very close to the way i did it. It's a little bit simpler actually as i had seperate handlers which is unnecessary in my case. Thanks a lot!